How to cache user-specific data in CloudFront while ensuring data freshness when cookies are forwarded?
Question:
I'm working on a web application that displays user-specific data based on a session cookie. Given the large number of users, we want to cache this data using AWS CloudFront to improve performance and reduce load on our origin servers.
However, the user-specific data can change when the user updates their account settings. Ideally, we want to cache this data in CloudFront but also ensure that users always see the most recent version of their data.
The Challenge:
CloudFront supports caching based on cookies, but if cookies are forwarded (all or a subset), CloudFront does not support conditional requests using If-Modified-Since or If-None-Match headers. This limitation prevents CloudFront from checking whether the cached data is stale or if the data has changed since it was last cached.
Any suggestions or best practices for handling this scenario would be greatly appreciated!
What I've tried:
I read the AWS CloudFront documentation on caching content based on cookies. It explains that CloudFront can cache different versions of content based on the values of one or more cookies.
I configured CloudFront to forward a subset of cookies to the origin.
Enabled caching for user-specific data based on these cookies.
I expected that after the initial request, subsequent requests with the same cookie would hit the CloudFront cache and serve the cached version of the user-specific data.
However, I observed that the data wasn't being cached, or if it was, CloudFront wasn't serving the cached data as I anticipated.
